# KnockoutJS unable to parse bindings when using RequireJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, requirejs

I have two select lists. The second one should be populated depending on the value of the first and data returned from an ajax request:

```
<select id="parent" data-bind="options: parentOptions, value:selectedParentOption, optionsText: 'parent_name'"></select>
<select id="children" data-bind="value:selectedChildOption, visible:hasChildOptions">
   <!-- ko if:hasChildOptions -->
       <!-- ko foreach: children -->
           <option data-bind="text: child_name, option:$data"></option>
       <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

I had it working before, but am trying to abstract functionality into separate modules with RequireJS:

```
// VIEWMODEL MODULE
define(["knockout", "ajax"], function(ko, ajax) {
return function ViewModel()
{
        self = this;
        self.parentOptions = ko.observable();
        self.selectedParentOption = ko.observable();
        self.hasChildOptions = ko.computed(function(){
            if(!self.selectedParentOption()) return false;
            if(!self.selectedParentOption().has_children)) return false;
            childOptions = ajax.loadChildOptions(self.selectedParentOption().id);
            childOptions.success(function(data){
                self.childOptions(data);
            })
            return true;
        })
        self.childOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedChildOption = ko.observable();
}
});

//AJAX MODULE
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'parentoption', 'childoption'], function($, ko, ParentOption, ChildOption){
    function loadParentOptions () {
        return $.getJSON('get_parent_options', function(data){
            var mappedParentOptions = $.map(data, function(item){
                 return new ParentOption(item.id, item.parent_name, item.has_children);
            })
            return mappedParentOptions;
        })
    }

    function loadChildOptions (parentId) {
        return $.getJSON('get_child_options', { parent: parentId}, function(data){
            var mappedChildOptions = $.map(data, function(item){
                return new ChildOption(item.id, item.child_name);
            })
            return mappedChildOptions;
        })
   }

   return {
        loadParentOptions: loadParentOptions,
        loadChildOptions: loadChildOptions
   }
});

//PARENT OPTION MODULE
define(["knockout"], function(ko){
    return function ParentOption(id, name, has_children){
        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.parent_name = ko.observable(name);
        this.has_children = ko.observable(has_children);
    }
})

//CHILD OPTION MODULE
define(["knockout"], function(ko){
    return function ChildOption(id, name){
        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.child_name = ko.observable(name);
    }
})
```

It gets kicked off with

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "viewmodel", "ajax"],function($, ko, ViewModel, ajax) {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    parentOptions = ajax.loadParentOptions();
    parentOptions.success(function(data){
        vm.parentOptions(data);
    });
});
```

It was working ok before I moved things into modules, so I'm pretty sure my json from the server is ok, but now I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: child_name is not defined;
Bindings value: text: child_name, option:$data
```

The first select list populates alright.

Comment: Are you using KO 2.1 or KO 2.0? 2.1 is AMD and require.js "ready" ... 2.0 needs a shim.

Comment: I'm using the latest version...

Comment: A few folks hit issues with RequireJS and Knockout in 2.1, particularly with the ko variable. Have you tested in 2.2? There were a few fixes applied for RequireJS, if I recall right.